# documentPicker delegate not called by UIDocumentPickerViewController

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, uidocumentpickerviewcontroller

I have the following `ViewController` that implements functionality for importing files into the app using the `UIDocumentPickerViewController`:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {
 
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
  }
  
  func importFromFiles(origin: UIViewController?) {
         
    let documentPicker = UIDocumentPickerViewController(documentTypes: [kUTTypeContent as String], in: .import)
    documentPicker.delegate = self
    documentPicker.allowsMultipleSelection = true
      
    origin?.present(documentPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    
  }
  
}
```

As you can see, the `importFromFiles` method receives a `ViewController`, which is simply the active VC. This method is called from the `AppDelegate`.

For now, the `documentPicker` method looks just as follows:

```
extension MyViewController: UIDocumentPickerDelegate {

  func documentPicker(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentsAt urls: [URL]) {
    print("Files picked")
  }

}
```

The picker is displayed and dismissed correctly, but the delegate is never called and therefore the `print` never executed.

### Edit 1

The call to the `importFromFiles` method is happening inside the `AppDelegate`. More specifically, it happens while defining a closure for a SwiftTweaks tweak:

```
MyTweaks.importFromFiles.addClosure {
  let topViewController = visibleViewController(root: self.window?.rootViewController)
  let myVC: MyViewController = MyViewController()
  myVC.importFromFiles(origin: topViewController)
}
```

Comment: Why are you creating a new instance of `MyViewController` just to show the document picker? Shouldn't you be calling `importFromFiles` on an existing and visible instance of a view controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you need to retain the main object as you have

```
let myVC: MyViewController = MyViewController()
myVC.importFromFiles(origin: topViewController)
```

inside where you present that picker here `MyViewController()` isn't retained so make it an instance var like

```
var main = MyViewController()
```

---

```
main.importFromFiles(origin:self)
```

Comment: where you created the var local inside `importFromFiles` ?

Comment: I tried both as a local variable in `importFromFiles` as a class attribute in `MyViewController` with the same result

Comment: I don't think he needs to strongly retain `documentPicker`. View hierarchy should strongly retain it so the issue should be someplace else

Comment: the issue as expected check updated answer , make it an instance var inside where you use it in your case inside `AppDelegate`

Comment: Yep, that worked. Sorry guys, really new to Swift here. Thanks!